# transferring settings to a new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, export

If I were to export this entire registry key (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer) could I then add it to the registry on my new pc?
My current PC has Windows 7 Ultimate and the new one will have Windows 7 Home Premium